# JDK 9.0.4 with Derby 10.14.2 cannot find the created table

Tags: java, sql, derby

I have tried to run some java class InsertApp which should push into existing table MYTABELLE22 a few rows. 
I'm getting from console Exception that table doesn't exist.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class InsertApp {
public static void main(String [] args) {
Connection con = null;
try {
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:derby:/Users/apolit/DerbyDatenbank;create=true");
  Statement sta = con.createStatement(); 

// insert 3 rows
  int count = 0;
  int c = sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MyTabelle22"
    + " (ID, MYKEY, CONTENT)"
    + " VALUES (1, 1, 'Bellevue')");
  count = count + c;

  c = sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MyTabelle22"
    + " (ID, MYKEY, CONTENT)"
    + " VALUES (2, 2, 'Hull')");
  count = count + c;

  c = sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MyTabelle22"
    + " (ID, MYKEY, CONTENT)"
    + " VALUES (3, 2, 'W. York')");
  count = count + c;
  System.out.println("Number of rows inserted: "+count);

  sta.close();
  con.close();        
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

[Please see also print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MO5h.png)

Comment: Have you tried to write your table name in upper case as it is in the database?
It is possible that the derby database has case sensitive functionality. And please update your question with Exception or log which has generated in your console.

Comment: Hi @Dushyant Tankariya, the Exception please see in print screnn below the code in my post. Sorry it's german and it meas that table dosen't exist. Yes in upper case MyTabelle22 and MYTABELLE22 both...

Answer (score 1):

Three common reasons for "table does not exist" when you think you've already created the tables:

1. You are connecting to a different database than you think you were connecting to, and since you specified "create=true" on the Connection URL, Derby quietly created a new empty database for you.
2. If You are using the "in-memory" configuration of Derby, which means that when the database is closed (or your application exits), all the contents of the database disappear.
3. You are connecting to the database as a different user, and you
   aren't issuing the SET SCHEMA statement, so you are using them
   default schema name, which is based on your user name, and so the
   two schemas are different and have completely different tables, so
   the table you created doesn't seem to exist when you use the other
   schema.

[SET SCHEMA STATEMENT](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html)

Comment: Possible reason #4 might be that they simply haven't done a CREATE TABLE in the first place.

Comment: I have created in the database schema 'FLIGHTS'. Is it sufficient to set schema in the DriverManager?  `"jdbc:derby:/Users/apolit/MyDB/NewDerby/currentSchema='FLIGHTS';create=true")`

Comment: Yes, Here you don't need to set currentSchema='FLIGHTS' because you are connecting to the database outside the system directory. you can directly write `"jdbc:derby:/Users/apolit/MyDB/NewDerby/FLIGHTS;create=true"` **Note:** Once connected, such a database becomes a part of the Derby system, even though it is not in the system directory. This means that it takes on the system-wide properties of the system and no other instance of Derby should access that database. It is recommended that you connect to databases only in the system directory.

Comment: @GordThompson, Yes, _#4 might be that they simply haven't done a CREATE TABLE_ This can be a possible reason but He has already attached the screenshot in question and we can see he has already created that table.

Comment: I have tried to compile with Java 8, 9 and 12, the schema FLIGHTS is created, the connection is working but I still get Exception: `Exception: Tabelle/View 'MYTABELLE23' ist nicht vorhanden.`which means the table MYTABELLE23 doesn't exist.

Comment: In Newly created SCHEMA FLIGHTS does Table MYTABLE Exist? And have you close all other connection to this SCHEMA before start execution of your code?

Comment: Many thanks to all for answers. It's working now after I have changed the value of executeUpdate to `FLIGHTS.MYTABELLE`. It is not working if I put the schema to the DriverManager path of the database. I wonder why.. Cheers